# Allows CSS Grid columns to be shorter than the Grid Gap to prevent overflow

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm working on my [grid system](https://v4.tocas-ui.com/en-us/grid.html) that allows up to 16 columns per row and each was divided with `1rem` gap.

[image]

There can be 4 columns in a row if each column takes 4 wide (`4 x 4 = 16`).

[image]

And there can only be one column per row if each takes 16 wide.

[image]

### Problem

When I'm shrinking the Grid, the column goes overflow.

[image]

The columns can shrink, but it couldn't be smaller than the Grid Gap.

> 1rem (Gap) * 16 (Columns per row) = 16rem

Hence the Grid cannot be shorter than `16rem`.

[image]

*※ The black border indicates the Grid container.*

Since it didn't happen with Flexbox, I wonder if there's any style allows the column to be shorter than the Grid Gap, so my Grid can be shorter than `16rem`?

### Code

Grid

```css
.ts-grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(16, minmax(0, 1fr));
}
```

Columns

```css
.ts-grid .column {
    grid-column: auto / span 1;
}
```

Comment: That's what media queires are for.

Comment: @Paulie_D I have tried with Media Queries, but some containers are small on a Desktop screen which can't trigger mine Media Queries conditions. I'm waiting for [Container Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries) :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `min()` on the gap to decrease it when the container is small:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: min(1rem, 5%);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, minmax(0, 1fr));
  border:1px solid;
}

.grid>div {
  height:50px;
  background:red;
}
.grid > div:only-child {
  grid-column: span 16;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```